# Regex for replacing `co(function *...)` with `async function ...`

Tags: node.js, regex, async-await

I've used [co](https://github.com/tj/co) extensively in node apps and packages and I would like update some of them with async/await using regex, if possible.

The`yield` from co is just a simple replace with `await`. The regex part comes with `co(function *...)`, which should be replaced with `async function ...`, the `...` staying the same.

The last `)` is the tricky part, since there would be many other `)` inside the function. The regex would have to check for a `(` and ignore the next `)` until it finds a `)` without a pair.

A simple hack would be to replace `co(function *` with `(async function`, but then I'd still need to replace `(async ...)` with `async ...` in many places, and I'm not sure how to tackle that last `)`.

I'm sure a regex expert would find this trivial, and it would benefit everyone making the upgrade to async/await!

Comment: No, the `...` part is absolutely non-trivial. And you'd be much better off by solving this with a javascript parser than regex. Try looking for e.g. a babel plugin that is capable of doing this, or write your own.

Comment: If there's no way to get the first ')' without a pair and capture the in-between text then I'll have to go for a programmatic approach. I might make a package out of it and post it back here if there's no other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [package](https://github.com/kesarion/co-async-migrate) for this task.

Install:

```
npm i co-async-migrate -g
```

Run:

```
co-async-migrate /path/to/dir
```

It should replace co/yield with async/await in all the files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookahead to keep the last ')' out.

Look at this regex:

```
(?<S>(?<co>co\()(?<f>\w+)(?<S3> \*)(?<body>.+(?=(?<end>[)]+))))
```

The group 'body' should match your function body (indicated as '...') while 'end' is the negative lookahead to exclude the last ')'.

This is a test: https://regex101.com/r/tVQHEX/2/

Comment: It must remove that last ')', though.